# Oracle DBSAT Tool Report Error

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, python-3.x, security

I need to assess the security of my oracle database using DBSAT tool.
I am using oracle 11g that is hosted by RHEL 5.9 OS

I was able to run DBSAT collector.  However, i failed to run DBSAT report due to having a python version (2.4) which is less than python 2.6
I needed to install python 2.6 or later.  So i installed python 3.6 and i could verify the following:

`#which python`
/usr/bin/python

`# which python3`
/usr/local/bin/python3

Now when i try to run DBSAT report it says that i need to install python 2.6 or later.  What am i missing here?

```
$ ./dbsat report db04
```

This tool is intended to assist in you in identifying potential
vulnerabilities in your system, but you are solely responsible for
your system and the effect and results of the execution of this tool
(including, without limitation, any damage or data loss). Further,
the output generated by this tool may include potentially sensitive
system configuration data and information that could be used by a
skilled attacker to penetrate your system. You are solely responsible
for ensuring that the output of this tool, including any generated
reports, is handled in accordance with your company's policies.

Error: Python version 2.6 or later is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.  Since i was using Oracle EBS, then i had to add python binary path in environment source file.